# Gulp: how to watch multiple files and perform a task for only the changes files?

Tags: gulp, gulp-watch

I wanna do this thing:

I have a folder with many js files. When I save one of them, I want to save the minified file in other folder.

I got it partially, because my script watch many files and when I change one, all files are copied and minified to the destination folder.

I discover recently that gulp.run is not used anymore.

If someone could help me, I'll be greatful.

I was trying this way:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var jshint = require('gulp-jshint');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
var watch = require('gulp-watch');

var files_dev = "./_sys/js/private/*.js";
var path_prod = "./_sys/js/public/";

gulp.task('dist-file', function(file) {
    gulp.src(file)
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest(path_prod));
});

gulp.task('default', function() {
    gulp.watch(files_dev).on("change", function(file) {
        gulp.run('dist-file');
    });
```

Comment: the gulp.watch callback function receives an event parameter with a path property pointing to the file that triggered the event.  It would be helpful if you posted your code.

Comment: sorry for not putting my code. As you could see, on task default I need to send file as parameter for my task dist-file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

dist-file doen't need to be a gulp task, you can make that a function which you can pass the file or glob to process.  Also watch is part of gulp now so you shouldn't need gulp-watch.

```
var jshint = require('gulp-jshint');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');

var files_dev = "./_sys/js/private/*.js";
var path_prod = "./_sys/js/public/";

function uglifyFile (file) {
    gulp.src([file])
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(path_prod));
}

gulp.task('watch-test', function() {
    gulp.watch(files_dev).on("change", function (event) {
        uglifyFile(event.path);
    });
});
```